# How to specify which topic to listen to in kafka confluent connector?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have been working on a kafka connector lately & i wanted to know where to configure the topics my sink connector's worker task should listen at.

Typically a SinkConnectorConfig looks like this

```
name=MySinkConnector
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.operative.creative.bi.sink.MySinkConnector
topics=demo
filePath=/tmp/output.txt
```

and these settings can be overridden when using the rest-proxy to control the worker configs. I want to know where do we specify the topic.

I know the property file defines a property called `"topics"` but i didn't see anything reading it in the boiler plate code.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
topic = props.get(TOPIC_CONFIG);
```

Have a look at https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html#connector-example, and also https://gist.github.com/jcustenborder/b9b1518cc794e1c1895c3da7abbe9c08

Comment: hi @Robin thanks for answering, i also have another question if you care to answer, is there any way of directly receiving JsonNode in SinkRecord values ?